# send commands to process

Tags: java, firefox

I wanna to create a programm which starts a Textfield.
In the Textfield I can write commands that will start
another process.

Example:
Textfield: "open firefox olaf"
Then the programm start firefox. Olaf is the Signal that the 
command ends.

My programm compare the Textfield `String` array 
with a commands `String` array and if for example 
the word "open" equal in both string array the be run
in a switch case method the following method "open".
thats works good.

My Problem:
Now I wanna a command like this:
Textfield: "type in firefox www.web.de olaf"
The programm should focused on firefox and should typen in firefox
"www.web.de", but I don't know how to do this. 
I don't wanna use the robot class with 
`robot.keyPressed()`

Also I wanna to type in the textfield of the websites.

Why I do this? 
I just wanna learn java and use Voice speeches, so I dont need to type "open firefox olaf".
I can just said it;)

if I need to do with C++ it's okay

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class KeyEventClass extends JFrame implements KeyListener, FocusListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public KeyEventClass(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.addKeyListener(this);
        this.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

        this.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated( WindowEvent e ){
                field.requestFocus();
                field.setText("");
            }
        }); 
    }


    String[] Commands = {"open"};  
    String[] Input = {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""} ;
    int i = 0;


    // Save the input in the String[] Input Variable but without VK_SPACE    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ 

        if(i > 20) { System.out.println("Error Index over..");}
        if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){

            i++;

        }
        if( e.getKeyChar() != KeyEvent.VK_SPACE ) Input[i] += e.getKeyChar();

    }

    // Compare Input and Commands    
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if( Input[i].compareTo("olaf")==0){ // olaf is a Signal of the end of the command line
            for(int k =0; k< Commands.length;k++){
                for(int z=0; z < Input.length;z++){

                    if(Input[z].compareTo(Commands[k])==0){

                        switch(k){
                        case 0: open(Input[z+1]);  //after start follow the name of the process 
                                System.out.println("case0 = open"); 
                                delete();
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void open(String process){

        try {
            Robot robot= new Robot();
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                    "C:\\Verknupfung\\"+process+".lnk");         //"C:\\Verknupfung\\" is a Path to start Process
            pb.start();

            robot.delay(1000);

            this.requestFocus();                                //set focus on KeyEventClass after start process

            } catch (Exception x) {System.out.println("Error to starts process:"+x);}   
    }

    public void delete(){
         for(int k=0;k< Input.length;k++) Input[k] = "" ;
         i=0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KeyEventClass();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {  
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Assuming that this is not some sort of homework assignment: you might want to prefer to not reinvent the wheel. Instead, Could it be that you want to build something that allows you to test web pages in firefox? If so, you should do some research of testing tools like fitnesse or others can give you what you need.

Comment: With is not kind of homework. I wanna learn java and with this Programm i can use Voice speeches, so i dont need to type "open firefox olaf"

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line arguments to achieve that.

./firefox www.stackoverflow.com

so u can use the ProcessBuilder to pass it in :

```
String urlAddress = someJTextField.getText();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/firefox", urlAddress);
pb.start();
```

Comment: Okay thats works good, but how i can type in textfields of the website?